# How to fix code 401 when auto filling google forms using google sheets scripts editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to develop a program that automatically fills out a google form using the data provided in google sheets.

This is my code.

```
function auto_data_entry() {
  var formURL = "(URL of the form would be put here)";
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet = workbook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var full_name = worksheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var year = worksheet.getRange("B2").getValue();   
  var month = worksheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var day = worksheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var period = worksheet.getRange("E2").getValue();

  var datamap = 
  {
  "entry.1901360617": full_name,
  "entry.43103907_year": year,
  "entry.43103907_month": month,
  "entry.43103907_day": day,
  "entry.1047848587": period
  };

  var options = 
  {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": datamap
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options); //Line 27

}
```

However, it returns...

```
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401.
Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" 
content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... 
(use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 27, file "Code")
```

Is the problem that I am using a school owned google account or that there is an error with my code.

I am very lost and would appreciate it if someone could help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) because you can use the [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) and the [Class ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response).  This code will help you with your issue:

```
function autoDataEntry() {

  // Get the desire form with its questions and create
  // a response to later be submitted 
  var form = FormApp.openById("YOUR-FORM-ID");
  var formResponse = form.createResponse();
  var formQuestions = form.getItems();

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet = workbook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // Get all the needed values in the second row 
  var answers = worksheet.getRange("A2:E2").getValues();

  answers[0].forEach((answer, answerNumber) => {
    // Get the question depending of its type
    var question = getQuestion(formQuestions, answerNumber);
    // Create the response to your question with the value obtained in the sheet
    var formAnswer = question.createResponse(answer);
    // Add the answer to the response
    formResponse.withItemResponse(formAnswer);  
  });
  // submit the form response  
  formResponse.submit();

}
```

What I did was to get the form where you want to send your response and the sheet where the answers are. Then I iterated through those answers to add them to the respective question, which would be added to the form response. When that process is finished, then you only need to submit the form response.

### Edit

I modified my code by adding the following function and calling it inside the `forEach` in my `autoDataEntry` function:

```
// This function will return the question as the requiered type
function getQuestion(formQuestions, answerNumber){
  var questionType = formQuestions[answerNumber].getType();
  switch(questionType){
    case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
      return formQuestions[answerNumber].asTextItem();
    case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
      return formQuestions[answerNumber].asMultipleChoiceItem();
    case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
      return formQuestions[answerNumber].asDateItem();
  }
}
```

In that way, you will get the proper question type as the situation requires as long you have set it as a condition in the switch statement. You can see all types in [Enum ItemType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can you make the code deal with multiple-choice questions and questions that ask you for a date?

Comment: I modified my code so it can accept multiple type of questions

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider mark it as the correct answer in order to let other people in the future know my answer works. You can check [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to do it.